# Python Boxplot - Pandas and Matlabplot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
    def totFatboxPlot():
    stud_dataframe.boxplot(column = ["TotalFat"], grid = False) 
    plt.title("2(b): Boxplot of Total Fat")
    plt.suptitle("")
    
totFatboxPlot();
```

For some weird reason, this gives me a "histogram" type "boxplot. Please see attached picture. What am I doing wrong?[Boxplot but histogram-like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zraoJ.png)

However if I used the "By" it seems to work fine. But I do not want the by.

```
stud_dataframe.boxplot(by ='SpecialDiet', column =['TotalFat'], grid = False)
```

Comment: It looks like it was plot on top of a previous figure. Could you provide sample data ? Maybe adding plt.figure() before the boxplot, and plt.show() after it could work out

Comment: @hugolmn that was exactly it! I was trying to draw over the previous barchart. Using plt.show() solved the issue. Thank you SO MUCH!